# Facebook share with SCFacebook with Objective-c issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Current I've implemented functionality for facebook share with SCFacebook library.
But I'm getting error when share facebook.

The error I'm getting is `The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`

The code I'm using is.
For `permission` I'm using this code.

```
[SCFacebook initWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_about_me",
                                      @"user_birthday",
                                      @"email",
                                      @"user_photos",
                                      @"user_events",
                                      @"user_friends",
                                      @"user_videos",
                                      @"public_profile"]
                 publishPermissions:@[@"manage_pages",
                                      @"publish_actions",
                                      @"publish_pages"]
 ];
```

And for `share action`

```
                [SCFacebook loginCallBack:^(BOOL success, id result) {
                    if (success) {
                        NSLog(@"success");
                        [SCFacebook feedPostWithMessage:@"String" callBack:^(BOOL success, id result) {
                            if (success) {
                                NSLog(@"%@", [result description]);
                            }else{
                                NSLog(@"%@", [result description]);
                            }
                        }];
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"%@", [result description]);
                    }
                }];
```

As my research, With administrator account, we don't need to submit permission for review.

I'm testing with administrator account which is in developers.facebook.com in my facebook app.
I'm not sure why this error is occured.

I'm looking for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know how to use SCFacebook library I don't mind that. I only need what the issue is.

Comment: So, did the user get asked for publishing permission in the login dialog, and did they grant it?